# Which SPL Exception should I use when validating set data before a process?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, exception

I'm struggling to get my head around when to use a couple of the [PHP SPL Exceptions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php), specifically in the below scenario,

```
class MyClass {
    protected $data1;
    protected $data2;

    public function setData1($data1) {
        $this->data1 = $data1;
    }

    public function setData2($data2) {
        $this->data2 = $data2;
    }

    public function invokeProcess() {
        $this->validateData();
    }

    protected function validateData() {
        if(!$this->data1) {
            // Which Exception do I throw? See explanation below
        }

        if($this->data1 && $this->data2) {
            // Which Exception do I throw? See explanation below
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class which is constructed. The user then sets some data on the object, and invokes a process. The first thing this process does is validate the data on the object to make sure required data is present, data combinations are correct, etc, and if they aren't, an Exception needs to be thrown.

**So what Exceptions do I throw?**

My validation checks for two scenarios really,

1. Missing data, a.k.a. data that has not been set.
2. Bad combination of data.

For #1, I'm torn between `BadMethodCallException`, `RuntimeException`, and `LogicException`. And for #2, I think it's just a `LogicException`?

So, which ones so I use?

**Note:** Before anyone asks, I can't have required data as parameters in the constructor due to some data only being required when other data is set, etc.

Comment: I think none of these exceptions really fits your situation. Why don't you just declare your own `ValidationException`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *have* to use an SPL exception, that would be `RuntimeException`. That's the one that refers to an error that can only be detected at runtime (such as bad input data).

`LogicException` would be an inappropriate choice, as it [refers to a logic error *in your program*](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php), not in the data it receives. Think of a `LogicException` as a panic button when your program detects that a condition that must *always* be true is not (contrast this with a condition that *should* be true for the program to perform its intended function).

[`BadMethodCallException`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) would also be inappropriate since it represents an

> Exception thrown if a callback refers
>   to an undefined method or if some
>   arguments are missing.

Some data your logic needs may be missing, but there's no method call without the correct number of arguments there.

In your shoes I would either define my own exceptions (derived from `RuntimeException`), or use `RuntimeException` directly.

Comment: I don't *have* to use SPL, I just don't see the point of extending and creating my own when one of the SPL Exceptions fits the bill. I agree, `Runtime` and `BadMethodCall` seem like the best options. That is what I thought and wanted some clarification.

Comment: @Stephen: I wrote that `BadMethodCall` would *not* be a good option :)

Comment: Yeah, I re-read the definition anyway and spotted that. Going on definition, `RuntimeException` is definitely the right choice. Thanks again.

Comment: But the SPL InvalidArgumentException is exectly for the situation when your program receives bad input data. And it extends *LogicException*. How do you explain that?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that none of the pre-existing exceptions seems to answer your needs, **why not create your own exceptions ?**

For instance, you could have :

- A super-class called `ValidationException`, that would extend `Exception`.
- That would be inherited by two sub-classes :

  - `ValidationException_MissingData`
  - `ValidatonException_BadCombination`

You do not necessarily have to use the pre-existing SPL exceptions, if they don't fit your situation : the exceptions mecanism is powerful enough to let you define whatever you need -- and that's what's done by most Frameworks, for instance.

*For more details on the how, see [**Extending Exceptions**][1].*

Answer (score 1):

I would personally throw an [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) in each `set*()` method.

Comment: I already do, but that validates the data being set, not that it is present and valid in combination with other data when the process is invoked.

Comment: And you would also have to use `UnexpectedValueException` in conjunction with `InvalidArgumentException` for the record :)